# Deploy Create-React-App on a remote Windows Server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, iis, create-react-app

I am an inexperienced intern working with a remote Windows Server and React. The Windows Server is running in the company network. I have created a dynamic React website with a NodeJs backend and React Router. I have only ran it on the localhost development server. I want to try to deploy it on the remote Windows Server and give it a custom domain name (Something which can be accessed like servername/myreactapp/).

So far, I have had no success trying to make it work with IIS, even with a web.config file (I get 404 and 500 errors). I am currently making it work by actually running the development server and the nodejs server in the Windows Server, and I access it through the server IP at port 3000.

An improvement would be to be able to access the port through the server name (like servername:3000, instead of the server_ip:3000), but ideally I want to be able to access it like servername/myreactapp/.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you using express and issexpress? It has been awhile since I deployed to IIS but here is an article that might help in current context https://medium.com/@richardhaines_6992/hosting-a-create-react-app-on-iis-e8be9a1f0a86

Comment: If by express you mean expressJS, yes. I am using the normal ISS. Yes I saw tried what was in the article, with no avail :(

Comment: I do remember it being a pain but cannot remember enough to help you. I actually ran into this issue where the person had done it and forgot. Mostly it's because it is a pain lol. Try this: https://dev.to/petereysermans/hosting-a-node-js-application-on-windows-with-iis-as-reverse-proxy-397b

Comment: Phew, it works partially. I can't use it without messing up the other websites on the server. I'll find a way around it, but this sets me on the right track. Thank you.

Comment: No problem sir glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution would be to run your app on port 80 then you will not have to specify the port number.

The best solution would be to set up Nginx on the server and proxy_pass / route to port 3000.

Answer (score 0):

If its running on localhost, which would be port 80, the url would be like http://your_server_name:80, and would be accessible by anyone on the same network, as long as your authentication allows it.

Comment: Yes, but I get an Invalid Host Header instead. I looked up some solutions, but it didn't work for me.